# tableau get data from 5 database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, tableau-api

i have 4 custom sql which are joined differently as shown in image attached getting data from jivo_all_branches in sql server.

[image]
Now these same tables are in other 4 database as well .Database names are grass, juice, database1,database2,datamodel1 .

```
Now i have to get data such that it gets from all 5 database



one custom sql named "INV1 + RIN1" which i have modified to



Select T0.ItemCode

, T0.ItemName

, T1.ItmsGrpNam

, T0.OnHand

, T0.IsCommited

, Linetotal



From [Jivo_All_Branches_Live].[dbo].OITM T0

Left Join [Jivo_All_Branches_Live].[dbo].OITB T1

on T0.ItmsGrpCod = T1.ItmsGrpCod



UNION ALL



Select T0.ItemCode

, T0.ItemName

, T1.ItmsGrpNam

, T0.OnHand

, T0.IsCommited

, T0.linetotal



From [database1].[dbo].OITM T0

Left Join [database1].[dbo].OITB T1

on T0.ItmsGrpCod = T1.ItmsGrpCod



UNION ALL



Select T0.ItemCode

, T0.ItemName

, T1.ItmsGrpNam

, T0.OnHand

, T0.IsCommited

, T0.linetotal



From [database2].[dbo].OITM T0

Left Join [database2].[dbo].OITB T1

on T0.ItmsGrpCod = T1.ItmsGrpCod
```

....and so on same for other databases as well.

So using union all is it correct or there is another way Like adding different database in data source pane.

Pls help

Comment: Create a view in your database. Connect Tableau to that single view.

Comment: but i have to connect to 5 different database